# Javafx stage does not resize when components are added

Tags: java, javafx, stage

So i have this application that gets some data and shows a graph!

When i start my program the graph data and the line chart is not created and therefore my program looks like this:

[image]

then when i press the "Hent data" button then my line graph is created and added on the center of the borderpane this makes the gui to look like this:
[image]

As you can see the application stage do not size to fit all the components.

However if i start the program up by creating a random graph (and not changing the size) the program will look like this:

[image]

in all of the examples my main stage code looks like this:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    bp = new BorderPane();
    bp.setTop(createTopPane());
    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().add(bp);
    bp.setCenter(createCenter());
    AnchorPane leftPane = new AnchorPane();

    leftPane.setPrefWidth(20);
    Separator vSeparator = new Separator(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    bp.setRight(leftPane);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().addAll("test.css", "calendarstyle.css");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(500);
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(527);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

How can i make sure that the stage stays the size it should be to fit the graph even if the graph is not yet created?

Please note that i have already tried to change the primaryStage size when i click the button however this did not solve the problem

Comment: Anyone know how i can get the prefered size even after the components are added?,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(javaFxNode, 0.0);` and `AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(javaFxNode, 0.0);`static methods.  A value of 0 in both should 'stick' the sides of your chart to its container.  Of course you can use `setTopAnchor` and `setBottomAnchor` as well for the same issue in height.

Comment: Thank you for your response i will check and see if this works when i get back to work tomorrow